# Viewing exceptional Lie algebras via the classical ones

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, exceptional-groups

I've been trying to understand the exceptional Lie algebras through the classical ones that I am more familiar with. In particular I wanted to get a handle on the root spaces and most discussions that I've read focus on the compact case (e.g. Baez's approach via the octonions and the magic square constructions) while I am more interested in the complex/split story.

To make it more clear what I mean, a choice of Cartan subalgebra in $\mathfrak{sl}(V)$ is equivalent to a choice of decomposition of $V$ into lines $L_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus L_n$ (The Cartan subalgebra being the diagonal guys with respect to this decomposition). Then the root spaces are all the $L_i^* \otimes L_j = \hom(L_i,L_j) \leq \mathfrak{sl}(V)$. We can also do this for $\mathfrak{so}(V)$ and $\mathfrak{sp}(V)$ by choosing decompositions into isotropic lines and identifying them with $\bigwedge^2V$ and $S^2V$.

For $\mathfrak{e}_7$ we can make use of the above by taking a $\mathfrak{sl}_8$ subalgebra. In particular we can choose the Cartan subalgebra to be a Cartan subalgebra of this subalgebra. Let $V$ be 8-dimensional and $\mathfrak{sl}_8 = \mathfrak{sl}(V)$. Then there is a complement to $\mathfrak{sl}_8$ in $\mathfrak{e}_7$ which is $\mathrm{ad}(\mathfrak{sl}_8)$ invariant and it is isomorphic to $\bigwedge^4V$ as a $\mathfrak{sl}_8$ representation. So $\mathfrak{e}_7 = \mathfrak{sl}(V) \oplus \bigwedge^4V$ (not direct as a sum of Lie algebras) and we can see its root system this way. Again the Cartan subalgebra defines a decomposition $V = L_1 \oplus \cdots\oplus L_8$. The root spaces in the $\mathfrak{sl}(V)$ part are just as before and the root spaces in $\bigwedge^4V$ are all the $L_i \wedge L_j \wedge L_k \wedge L_l$.

I know it is possible to do this for $\mathfrak{e}_8$ as well viewing it as a copy of $\mathfrak{so}_{16}$ together with one of the spin representations of $\mathfrak{so}_{16}$. Is there a way to see the other exceptional Lie algebras in this manner? I don't think $\mathfrak{e}_6$ contains a simple subalgebra with the same rank as it but it does have subalgebras like $\mathfrak{sl}_3 \oplus\mathfrak{sl}_3 \oplus\mathfrak{sl}_3 $ and $\mathfrak{sl}_6 \oplus\mathfrak{sl}_2 $.

Are there any good references on this style of approach to the exceptional Lie algebras or a good way to see what the decompositions and root systems would be?

Edit: More recently, I have found some good notes on constructions of this form in J. Adams's ["Lectures on exceptional Lie groups"](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Lectures_on_Exceptional_Lie_Groups.html?id=a3XCft6dubIC&redir_esc=y)

Comment: You might be interested in John Baez's [notes](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/kostant/) on a talk of Kostant on $\mathsf E_8$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Élie Cartan himself, recognized and used the following description of $\mathfrak{e}_6$:  Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $6$ and let $W$ be a vector space of dimension $2$. Then there is a vector space splitting
$$
\mathfrak{e}_6 = \mathfrak{sl}(V)\oplus\mathfrak{sl}(W)\oplus \bigl(\Lambda^3(V)\otimes W\bigr)
$$
and, moreover,  $\mathfrak{e}_6$ is the Lie algebra of linear transformations of $A = \Lambda^2(V^*)\oplus (V\otimes W)$ that preserve a certain cubic form on $A$ that is invariant under the obvious representation of $\mathrm{SL}(V)\times\mathrm{SL}(W)$ on $A$.  (This $A$ is one of the two lowest dimensional linear representations of $\mathfrak{e}_6$, the other is its dual.)

I don't know that Élie Cartan ever noticed this, or wrote about it, but I think there is a description along the following lines: (maybe in Freudenthal or Dynkin):  Let $V_1$, $V_2$, and $V_3$ be three vector spaces of dimension $3$.  Then there is a decomposition
$$
\mathfrak{e}_6 = \mathfrak{sl}(V_1)\oplus\mathfrak{sl}(V_2)\oplus \mathfrak{sl}(V_3)\oplus (V_1\otimes V_2\otimes V_3)\oplus (V^*_1\otimes V^*_2\otimes V^*_3)
$$
as a module over the group $\mathrm{SL}(V_1)\times\mathrm{SL}(V_2)\times \mathrm{SL}(V_3)$.  I'll try to find the reference.

Comment: Thanks so much. Just to check I understand this. We can construct subalgebras of maximal rank like these by removing a node from the extended Dynkin diagram. Indeed this identifies some root subsystem of the original system. Is it then the case that the Lie algebra decomposes as the sum of this subalgebra and the span of the remaining root spaces on which the subalgebra acts?

Comment: @Callum, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395461/viewing-exceptional-lie-algebras-via-the-classical-ones#comment1013445_395500), a reductive Lie algebra always decomposes as the sum of a maximal Cartan subalgebra and the root spaces for that maximal torus, and those can be grouped as you please; for example, the maximal subalgebra can be grouped with enough root spaces to make up the Lie algebra of a maximal-rank subgroup, and the remaining ones added on separately.  (Sorry—I saw this on the front page and thought it was a new post; just noticed now it's from 2021.)

Comment: @LSpice I edited the question to include a reference I read more recently in case anyone was interested so that must have bumped it to the front somehow. Thanks for your comments nonetheless. I think the only thing I was missing when I wrote that comment was that if the first set of roots form a root subsystem then that subalgebra preserves the other span of root spaces which follows from basic properties of root spaces.

Comment: Ah, I [see](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395461/viewing-exceptional-lie-algebras-via-the-classical-ones/395500#comment1109290_395500).  So you were looking not just for a direct-sum decomposition as vector spaces, nor for a direct-sum decomposition as Lie algebras (where the summands would commute), but a decomposition $L = L' + I$ with $I$ a subspace of $L$ normalised by $L'$.

Comment: @LSpice yes exactly, so that I could view the exceptional Lie algebras as a classical Lie algebra together with one of its representations and thus help me understand them a bit better. (Obviously we are then still left with a challenge to understand the bracket on $I$, but it helped me get a better picture of what was going on)

Comment: As an example, the 56-dimensional representation of $\mathfrak{e}_7$ in my notation above is just $\bigwedge^2 V \oplus \bigwedge^2 V^*$ and the symplectic form on it is just $0$ on each of these summands and contraction between them which I find quite an easy way to view it. The invariant quartic form is a bit trickier but the reference I added to my question by Adams described it nicely in those terms so I thought I'd add it in in case it helped someone else as well.